# Is it possible to rewrite $\cosh(2x)-1$ as $2(\sinh^2(x))$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was given a problem and my solution was: $\cosh(2x)-1$. The answer given in the answer key, however was: $2(\sinh^2(x))$. I believe my answer is correct. Is it possible to rewrite my answer to get $2(\sinh^2(x))$?

For anyone who wants more info - the problem was:

> Find the derivative of: $y=\frac{\sinh(2x)-2x)}{2}$

Comment: Certainly. What are the definitions of $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ ?

Comment: Your answer is correct same result

Comment: analogous to $\cos(2x)-1=-2\sin^2(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using addition formula:
$$\cosh(2x)=\cosh^2(x)+\sinh^2(x)$$
Since $\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)=1$ we have
$$\cosh(2x)=1+\sinh^2(x)+\sinh^2(x)$$
$$\cosh(2x)-1=2\sinh^2(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

You can check for yourself since
$$
\cosh (x) = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}
$$
and
$$
\sinh (x) = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2} .
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  $\;\cosh(2x)-1=\dfrac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}2-1=\dfrac{e^{2x}-2+e^{-2x}}{2}=2\dfrac{(e^x-e^{-x})^2}4=2\sinh(x)^2$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\bigl(\cosh(2x)-1-2\sinh^2(x)\bigr)'&=2\sinh(2x)-2\cdot2\sinh(x)\cosh(x)\\&=2\sinh(2x)-2\sinh(x)=0,
\end{align}$$
hence $\cosh(2x)-1-2\sinh^2(x)$ is constant.  Now plug in $x=0$.